# How to remove x-Apple-data-detectors in Highchart in iOS. Due to this category names are hiding in line graph

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I am using highcharts for showing data. in iOS, Dynamically added x-apple-data-detectors due to this, category names are hiding. So Please help me to resolve this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehYW3.png)

I added six categories name in line graph. But it is showing only 2 category name. for remaining categories added dynamically anchor tag with x-apple-data-detectors.

Comment: Can you paste the image with the issue?

Comment: Hi morganfree, i added image can you please suggest solution ?